# FileNotFoundException not caught by IOException

Tags: java, exception, filenotfoundexception, ioexception

In my program I want to read a file and then analyze it. To do this I made this simple code :

```
BufferedReader br = null;
FileReader fr = null;
try {
  fr = new FileReader("E:\\Users\\myFile.txt");
  br = new BufferedReader(fr);

  [...]

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  try {

    if (br != null)
      br.close();
    if (fr != null)
      fr.close();

  } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately when my file doesn't exist I have a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` exception that is thrown. But when I read the doc of `java.io.FileNotFoundException` I can see that `java.io.IOException`is a superclass of `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

So, why does `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is not caught by `catch (IOException ex)`?

Also i know that I must do `catch (FileNotFoundExceptionex)` but I don't understand why I have this error.

Answer (score 1):

It **does**:

```
public void test() {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("E:\\Users\\myFile.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        System.out.println("OK");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Caught in try.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {

            if (br != null)
                br.close();
            if (fr != null)
                fr.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Caught in catch.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

prints

> Caught in try.
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Users\myFile.txt (The system cannot find the path specified) ...

BTW: You can use *try with resources* for a much more effective and tidy solution.

```
public void test() {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\Users\\myFile.txt"))){
        System.out.println("OK");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Caught in try.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @EtienneL - What version of Java are you using - this is using Java 8.

Comment: All the time I have this error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\\Users\\myFile.txt (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)`

Comment: It is really strange because I am also using Java 8.

Comment: @EtienneL - What makes you think it is not being caught?

Comment: @EtienneL "All the time I have this error java.io.FileNotFoundException" So it *is* being caught?

Comment: Because I have the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\\Users\\myFile.txt (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)`.

Comment: @EtienneL - That is what `e.printStackTrace();` does.

Comment: Ok my bad I dind't understand what you were saying... I am so stupid.

Comment: Thank you, my code is correct and it was only the `e.printStackTrace`...